# nmap and nmap -sL giving me contradictory results

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

I want to find the names of all PCs in some subnet.

In order to do this, I type in the following command:

```
nmap x.x.x.0/24.
```

(Whereby each x stands for one digit.)

An alternative command to achieve the same thing is supposed to be this:

```
nmap -sL x.x.x.0/24.
```

The only difference to the first alternative is supposed to relate to the format in which the results are printed to the command line.

However, not only the format differs but also the content. The result of the first command tells me for each computer on the subnet that it's up.

The result of the second command tells me for each computer on the subnet that it's down!!

What is going on here? Why is the first command telling me the opposite of the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extracted from nmap documentation:

> (-sL option). This feature simply enumerates every IP address in the given target netblock(s) and does a reverse-DNS lookup (unless -n was specified) on each.

That's because -sL is only listing and nothing more. And your other command without parameters is performing real scan.